# Designing iOS app, caching and accessing data from web service

Tags: ios, xcode

Whats the best way to store and access data from an iOS app.

I want to load in application information when the application starts. Such as account pictures, email addresses... etc.

Then each controller has other data that it loads in for customers owned by this account. I know how to call web services and use core data.

Is there some existing template or framework for storing, caching and accessing data? Should I include it all in some singleton class so that each controller can access the data?

Comment: just FYI, Core Data has pretty huge overhead in terms of learning and complexity. only use it if you need it - which usually means only use it if you need persistent local storage with FAST access and LOADS of data. if you are just storing a few piece of data for one of two user accounts, I would personally avoid Core Data - but that's a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward, you already have a "singleton" for what you want to do, which is your database and its managed object context. What you can do is pass this database object from controller to controller, or have as you say a method to get the singleton object and load whatever you need using fetched results controller and predicates.

For the data retrieval part (from your web service) you have 2 choices, considering you get your data in chunks and not one big pull: you could make each controller make the necessary calls to your web service that are relevant to the data you're looking to store in the database, otherwise you can create a class with several methods for each kind of data you require and have this deal with the saving and retrieving from the managed object context.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898269/ios-core-data-architecture-tips-wanted) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207539/ios-app-architecture-sample-for-synchronizing-coredata-against-web-service) seem very related to what you're looking for.